# Hibernate stop lazy loading

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am new to hibernate.
I use the below code to get my object

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true,propagation=Propagation.NEVER)
public StaffSkillChecklist listSkillMatrixByChecklistIdForStaff(Long checklistid, Long staffId) {

    StaffSkillChecklist sc = (StaffSkillChecklist) em.unwrap(Session.class)
            .createCriteria(StaffSkillChecklist.class, "staffchecklist")
            .createAlias("staffchecklist.staffSkillRatingSet", "staffSkillRating", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)
            .setFetchMode("staffSkillRating", FetchMode.JOIN)

            .createAlias("staffchecklist.skillChecklist", "skillChecklist", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)
            .setFetchMode("skillChecklist", FetchMode.JOIN)

            .createAlias("staffSkillRating.skillGroup", "skillGroup", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)
            .setFetchMode("skillGroup", FetchMode.JOIN)
            .createAlias("staffSkillRating.skill", "skill", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)
            .setFetchMode("skill", FetchMode.JOIN)
            .createAlias("staffSkillRating.skillRating", "skillRating", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)
            .setFetchMode("skillRating", FetchMode.JOIN).addOrder(org.hibernate.criterion.Order.asc("id"))

            .add(Restrictions.and(Restrictions.eq("staffchecklist.staff.id", staffId),
                    Restrictions.eq("skillChecklist.id", checklistid)))
            .uniqueResult();

    return sc;
}
```

Now in my serviceclass, I need to iterate the object and convert to DTO but while doing so, hibernate queries the db again

```
public SkillChecklistDTO toDTO(SkillChecklist skillChecklist, int depth) {
        if (skillChecklist == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Set<SkillChecklistGroup> scgList = new HashSet<SkillChecklistGroup>();
//HIBERNATE WILL FIRE A QUERY again
        scgList = skillChecklist.getChecklistGroups();

        return dto;
    }
```

How do I stop hibernate from firing query again. My first query has everything I want.

Answer (score 0):

By default Hybernate applies lazy loading on OneToMany relationships.
So you should add fetch = FetchType.EAGER to your annotation.

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
```

You should also try to replace `.setFetchMode("skillChecklist", FetchMode.JOIN)` by `.setFetchMode("skillChecklist", FetchMode.EAGER)`

Comment: try to replace .setFetchMode("skillChecklist", FetchMode.JOIN) by .setFetchMode("skillChecklist", FetchMode.EAGER)